I have a confusion over the clustering, techniques involved and the scores. This is more about concept based since I am new to clustering models
What is astonishing to me is that the established norms for clustering data are not actually able to deduce the real results in my problem.
I created a K=2 clustering kmeans and kmeans-constrained (since i required within a specific number of clusters ). I applied model on two types of data once without applying any standardization or any transformation, and secondly applying quantile transformation followed by PCA ( once applied to all columns and then applied to over only specific columns containing large scale of values).
My problem is when i cross checked the cluster data with the real data the cluster formed from Kmeans-constrained and without any transformation was more efficiently capturing my data points, while yhe transformed data didn't.
Secondly the even evaluation metrics like silhouette (0.20) and kmeans-score (of the order of -10^5) cannot be considered good (i think!).
My data is about loan customers containing different features about their payment history and other details. My goal was something like to select the best among the worst customers) .
What could be yhe possible reason!?
Is it like clustering techniques are likea black box which can be unpredictable sometimes?
Is my result explainable and how can i defend the model ?
